# Обработчик ошибок FireBird

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте!
Меня интересует такой вопрос: как обработать ошибку FireBird о не заполненности полей со свойством `not null`? Суть проблемы заключается в том, что у меня есть форма на которой находится кнопка, делающая commit транзакции, и `dbedit`, который в свою очередь связан с полем, имеющим свойство `not null`. Нажав кнопку commit, при этом оставив dbedit пустым, я получаю ошибку FireBird. Можно ли как-то перехватить эту ошибку и написать в ней свой текст.
Язык Delphi.
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

лучше незаполненность полей проверять не в субд, а перед коммитом.

```
procedure MyProc;
begin
  ...
  if dbedit.text <> '' then
    // делаем коммит
    ...
  else
   // не делаем коммит
  ...
end;
```

Даже если и не такая, но **предварительная** проверка заполненности обязательных полей должна быть.

Answer (score 0):

Поясните, пожалуйста, какую кнопку Вы имеете ввиду: кнопку DBNavigator nbPost или обычный Button? В первом случае, в обработчике OnClick Навигатора имеется переменная, соответсвующая кнопкам Навигатора. А во втором - тоже OnClick. Проверяйте поле на пустоту в этих обработчиках, и все.

Comment: Пока писал, уважаемый @teanЫЧ уже ответил.